# Windby loadby sos clr does nothing

Tags: windbg, sos

I'm trying to debug a 64bit .NET 4.5.2 application and am having trouble loading the sos extension. My normal deal is to open up the x64 WinDbg executable, type in `.loadby sos clr` and go on about my business. Today, when I type that into WinDbg, it just stares at me and does nothing. Using any extension from the library gives an error message of "No export  found". I did this about a month ago on the same machine and it worked fine. My symbols are `srv*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`, which is pretty standard fare.

I then tried to load SOS directly using `.load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\SOS.dll` (the file exists, btw), and it also does nothing.

I suspect my company has blocked something, but I have no idea what it is or where to start.

Comment: WinDbg uses many tricks to enable debugging so if your company installs specific protection software on the machine, it can simply be blocked from working properly. The very first thing you should do is to talk to the system administrators and ask about recent changes to your machine.

Comment: is it listed in `.chain`? What does `lm fm clr` say? Is there a SOS.dll in that path? Have you tried loading that DLL with `.load`? Which version of WinDbg do you use?

Comment: BTW: `.loadby sos clr` never "does" anything visible. It will not display a message or whatever when it succeeds. It should do so when it fails, however.

Comment: Any feedback about what was asked in the comments?